# UIwindow not show after makekeyandvisible ,when Clock Alarm alert is showed?

Tags: iphone, clock, uiwindow

My  app's second window not show by using uiwindow makekeyandvisible, when the ipod Clock Alarm alert is presented,even I set my window's window level to alert level.any help?thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Second window?? I don't think it is recommended that you have more than 1 window in your app. Perhaps you need to display an alert. Have a look at UIAlertView. If you need to display large custom information in the component that pops up when the alarm goes off, display a Modal View Controller atop your main window.

HTH,

Akshay

Comment: modal view sometimes could be blocked to show by other model view,a second window seems has high level to show above other view,but also cann't show up when there is a clock alarm alert view.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish. If you are the one displaying the modal view in your app, it cannot be blocked by another modal view unless you yourself display another modal view.

Comment: I find out the reason is that clock alarm make application suspend ,even the application:handleOpenURL cann't make it become active.why>?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?